# C# merge two list, without duplicates and sum a field values

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that have **Id, Product, Quantity** properties. And I have created a generic list type of this class and some items values are same (as shown below). So, I want to merge same items without duplicates but also sum the **Quantity** fields values into one item and create a new generic list without duplicates but the Quantity fields values are sum. But I couldn't it anyway.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product p1 = new Product(1, "apple", 1);
        Product p2 = new Product(1, "apple", 1);
        Product p3 = new Product(1, "apple", 1);
        Product p4 = new Product(1, "apple", 1);
        Product p5 = new Product(2, "orange", 1);
        Product p6 = new Product(2, "orange", 1);
        Product p7 = new Product(3, "mango", 1);
        Product p8 = new Product(3, "mango", 1);
        Product p9 = new Product(3, "mango", 1);
        Product p10 = new Product(3, "mango", 1);

        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
        list.Add(p1);
        list.Add(p2);
        list.Add(p3);
        list.Add(p4);
        list.Add(p5);
        list.Add(p6);
        list.Add(p7);
        list.Add(p8);
        list.Add(p9);
        list.Add(p10);

        var list_collapsed = Collapse(list);

        foreach (var item in list_collapsed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id:{0} - Product: {1} - Quantity: {2}", item.Id, item.Name, item.Quantity);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static List<Product> Collapse(List<Product> ExpandedList)
    {
        List<Product> CollapsedList = new List<Product>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ExpandedList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CollapsedList.Count == 0)
            {
                CollapsedList.Add(ExpandedList[i]);
            }

            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < CollapsedList.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (ExpandedList[i].Id != CollapsedList[j].Id)
                    {
                        CollapsedList.Add(ExpandedList[i]);
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        CollapsedList[j].Quantity += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return CollapsedList;
    }
}

class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Product(int id, string name, int quantity)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

**The output:**

Id:1 - Product: apple - Quantity: 3
Id:2 - Product: orange - Quantity: 1
Id:2 - Product: orange - Quantity: 1
Id:3 - Product: mango - Quantity: 1
Id:3 - Product: mango - Quantity: 1
Id:3 - Product: mango - Quantity: 1
Id:3 - Product: mango - Quantity: 1

**But I need its output like here:**

Id:1 - Product: apple - Quantity: 3
Id:2 - Product: orange - Quantity: 2
Id:3 - Product: mango - Quantity: 4

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need this little query:

```
var list_collapsed = list
    .GroupBy(p => new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name } )
    .Select(g => new Product(g.Key.Id, g.Key.Name, g.Sum(p => p.Quantity)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do a GroupBy using Id field.  Then in each group you can sum up the Quantity fields

```
 public static List<Product> Collapse(List<Product> ExpandedList)
 {
 List<Product> CollapsedList = new List<Product>();

 var groupBy = ExpandedList.GroupBy(x => x.Id);

 foreach (var group in groupBy)
 {
  var first = group.FirstOrDefault();
  first.Quantity = group.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
  CollapsedList.Add(first);
 }

 return CollapsedList;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, linq is your friend:

```
var list_collapsed = products.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(g => new Product(0, p.Key, p.Sum(x => x.Quantity)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`var list_collapsed = products.GroupBy(p => p.id).Select(g => new Product(Id = g.Key.Id,Name = g.Key.Name,Quantity = g.Sum(p => p.Quantity) ).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
        var newList = from p in list
                      group p by p.Id
                      into g
                      select new Product(g.Key, g.Min(f => f.Name), g.Sum(p => p.Quantity));
```